# My last java question Problem that even my professor couldn't solve

Tags: java, servlets

I am writing my last java assignment (Yayy! - thanks to all of you that have helped me through the others).  In this one, I have to write a servlet that takes an age, marital status, house income and number of kids, goes out to a DB, and then returns the updated averages to the user. However, I am encountering *this* stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HouseSurvey$SurveyResults
    at HouseSurvey.doPost(HouseSurvey.java:23)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:709)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    at org.apache.catalina.servlets.InvokerServlet.serveRequest(InvokerServlet.java:419)
    at org.apache.catalina.servlets.InvokerServlet.doPost(InvokerServlet.java:169)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:709)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:868)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:663)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:80)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HouseSurvey$SurveyResults
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1338)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1187)
    ... 21 more
```

In the past, I have been guilty of posting too much code, not enough code etc. I apologize for my newbishness. Here is the class I have written:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class HouseSurvey extends HttpServlet {
    private final static String SURVEY_FILE = "HouseSurvey.dat";
    SurveyResults results;
    Household h;
    DecimalFormat form = new DecimalFormat("#,###,#00.00");

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  //make a printwriter to print the page
        File survey = new File(SURVEY_FILE);
        if (!survey.exists())    //check to see if the file exists
            results = new SurveyResults();
        else {     //If the file exists, read it the latest survey tallies
            try {
                ObjectInputStream ips = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(survey));
                results = (SurveyResults) ips.readObject(); //read the file into 'results'
                ips.close();   //close the input stream
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException f) {
                f.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        int ageValue = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("age")),
                childValue = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("children"));
        double incomeValue = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("income"));
        Boolean marriedValue;
        if (request.getParameter("status") == "married") {
            marriedValue = true;
        } else {
            marriedValue = false;
        }
        Household h = new Household(ageValue, childValue, incomeValue, marriedValue);
        results.totalResults(h);
        //Write results to disk.
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream ops = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(survey));
            ops.writeObject(results);
            ops.flush();
            ops.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        response.setContentType("text/html");       //contnent type for the responding webpage
        out.println("<html>\n" +
                "<head><title>Thanks!</tile></head>" +
                "<body>" +
                "   <h1 style='text-align:center'>RRC BIT Department - Household Survey</h1>" +
                "   <hr><br/>" +
                "   <h2 style='text-align:center'>Up to Date Survey Results</h2>" +
                "   <h4 style='left-margin:200px'>Average Age: " + results.getAvgAge() +
                "   <h4 style='left-margin:200px'>Average Number of Children: " + results.getAvgKids() +
                "   <h4 style='left-margin:200px'>Average Number of Married Respondents: " + results.getAvgKids() +
                "   <h4 style='left-margin:200px'>Average Number of Single Respondents: " + results.getTotalSingle() +
                "   <h4 style='left-margin:200px'>Average Income: " + results.getAvgIncome());
    }

    private class Household {
        private int age, children;
        private double income;
        private boolean married = false;

        /**
         * Method: Household
         * Constructor
         *
         * @ param age - age of person surveyed:int
         * @ param children - number of children person surveyed has:int
         * @ param married - true or false, used to determine married or single:boolean
         * @ param income - the family income of the person surveyed:double
         */
        private Household(int age, int children, double income, boolean married) {
            this.age = age;
            this.children = children;
            this.income = income;
            this.married = married;
        }

        //Getters
        private int getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        private int getChildren() {
            return children;
        }

        private double getIncome() {
            return income;
        }

        private boolean getMarried() {
            return married;
        }
    }

    private class SurveyResults implements Serializable {
        private double totalAge, totalChildren, totalMarried, totalSingle, totalIncome;

        /**
         * Method: SurveyResults
         * Used for totals
         *
         * @ param h - Household object created above:Household
         */
        private void totalResults(Household h) {
            if (h.getMarried()) totalMarried += 1;
            else totalSingle += 1;
            totalAge += h.getAge();
            totalChildren += h.getChildren();
            totalIncome += h.getIncome();
        }

        private double getTotalHouseholds() {
            return totalSingle + totalMarried;
        }

        private double getAvgAge() {
            return totalAge / getTotalHouseholds();
        }

        private double getAvgKids() {
            return totalChildren / getTotalHouseholds();
        }

        private double getTotalMarried() {
            return totalMarried;
        }

        private double getTotalSingle() {
            return totalSingle;
        }

        private double getAvgIncome() {
            return totalIncome / getTotalHouseholds();
        }
    }
}
```

I thought it was pretty damned close, so I went to ask my instructor.  He looked at it for about 20 minutes, and he couldn't figure it out.

I know that you guys are pretty damned clever (especially when it comes to into stuff), so if any of you could spare a moment to help a brother out.......

Comment: I think this one fits the too much code case :)

Comment: It looks like you are running Tomcat.  Are you running from within Eclipse or a stand-alone Tomcat installation?  How are you deploying your web app?

Comment: Could it be because `SurveyResults` is a non-static member class?

Comment: I am indeed running Tomcat.  I am running it from BlueJ. The web ap is in the proper folder, the class is in the proper folder, I have the classpath set is the SYS_DSN (all other servlets are running just fine).

Comment: How are you deploying this? Are you creating a war?

Comment: I need to downvote my own comment 1/2 :)

Answer (score 9):

It looks like you didn't upload all compiled `.class` files. Make sure you don't upload only `HouseSurvey.class`, but also all other `.class` files generated by the compiler. In your case, `HouseSurvey$SurveyResults.class` seems to be missing.

Comment: OH crap. Is that it? I though I only had to post the one class file. Thank you.

Comment: @unit -- every class defined in a .java source file turns into a separate .class file when the .java is compiled.  They aren't bundled.

Comment: No, I realized that after. This is the first time we have ever used inner-classes. Up to this point we have been doing everything as separate classes. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HouseSurvey$SurveyResults
```

I'd recommend creating a package for your Java classes.  Tomcat doesn't take too kindly to .class files in the default package.

You should be creating a WAR file and deploying that to the Tomcat /webapps directory.  Don't put your stuff into ROOT.

I'd also recommend that you not slam all this code into a servlet class.  You can't test or debug it without Tomcat if you do that.  The servlet should be doing very little: listen for HTTP requests, validate and bind input parameters, call methods on other classes to do the work, and then package the response into the appropriate output format.  That's it.  Other classes ought to be doing the heavy lifting.  Servlets are HTTP listeners.

Decompose your problem into smaller, bite sized pieces that you can test separately.

For example, do the database interactions in a class outside the servlet.  Test it thoroughly and put it aside.

Answer (score 0):

Make the class SurveyResults public. The readObject() method needs to find the definition for SurveyResult. And also the class should (most probably) be static.